# convert duration to seconds

Tags: sql, datetime, select

Im beginner using sql. Im creating new column

```
x1 = date_order - date_Delivery
```

to mesure the duration of waiting time of clients. My column X1: contains for example (00:10:24.949131, 01:00:01, 2 days 00:40:45). I want to convert this duration to seconds , in this case the second values will be 3601.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `(00:10:24.949131, 01:00:01, 2 days 00:40:45)` => you need to be more precise about the format, the SQL will not detect it by itself

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
extract(epoch from date_order - date_Delivery) / 60
```

This expression converts the interval to a number of seconds, that you can then divide by 60 to get the corresponding number of minutes.

Comment: @salsa: it looks good to me: 1 minute 43 seconds is about 1.7 minutes. Which result would you expect for that value?